How to bypass redirect when opening inspect element
I'm trying to use inspect element for aniwave but every time I open it I just get redirected to home page. Any help will be appreciated. If it's not possible, how can I view the html elements without inspecting element.
I tried deactivating breakpoint and I'll still get redirected
